# getScript() and data uri base64 giving net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, cryptojs

I have some code that is encrypted, so I use `AES` and Base64

```
var encrypted = "(some aes encrypted base 64 encrypted data uri)"
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "(key)");
var decstring = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
$.getScript( decstring, function() {
    console.log( "Script was succesfully decrypted." );
    call();
});
```

When i try this in a browser it says

> net::ERR_INVALID_URL

I go and see the url given and it contains an extra `?_=1483692592022` which ruins the data URI. I go in the console and the value of my `decstring` variable is without the extra bit at the end, and every time I refresh the number changes.
This is very annoying, somebody please help me.

Comment: The `?_=...` value at the end of the URL is a timestamp used to stop caching. It will not result in the error you're seeing. That is more likely caused by the decoding process not working correctly. Can you show a sample of the encoded string, or at the very least `console.log(decstring)` and tell us what it says.

Comment: well not really but i could make a new example one if you want

Comment: also without the function there the code works fine

Comment: That would be helpful -- a small sample please.

Comment: yeah i used the encrypt method, i used the value of it in the original version though

Comment: console.log(decstring) results the same as i expect it to be